# How to wait for new data from MongoDB in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a chat project, NodeJS has to wait 25 secs for new data from MongoDB, any alternatives?

```
while(true) {
    db.messages.find({
    ...
    }).then(result) => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            return result;
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
let secs = 0;
const iv = setInterval(() => {
        secs++;

        db.messages.find({
        ...
        }).then(result) => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                clearInterval(iv);

                res.json(result);
                return;
            }
        });

        if (secs === 25)
           clearInterval(iv);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: check change stream in MongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [changeStream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams)

```
const collection = db.collection('messages');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // process next document
});
```